# How do I create a new instance of a record?

Tags: clojure

Given that I have two objects defined (in this case records):

```
(defrecord rec1 [one two])
(defrecord rec2 [one two])
```

and I have these two records in (uninstanciated) in a list:

```
(def recs [rec1 rec2])
```

How is the best way to instanciate these two records in the list?

The following gives an exception

```
(map (fn [rec] (rec. 1 2)) recs)
```

because new and the dot constructor expects a classname-symbol. So what is the best way to go about this? So far reflection seems to be the only way:

```
(map #(clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeConstructor % (to-array [1 2 3])) recs)
```

This just seems like an overly ugly (and slow) way to perform the seemingly simple task of calling the constructor on an object. So what is the correct (or idiomatic) way?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear to me, but here are some observations:

- rec1 and rec2 are not different ctors of the same type, rather separate types each with 1 ctor (co-incidentally the two ctor have the same arity/ signature)
- your 'uninstatiated list' doesn't make sense.
- defrecord generates some helper functions for just this use...

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, here are some examples that might clarify your requirements...

```
(def r1 (->rec1 1 2))
;=> #user.rec1{:one 1, :two 2}

(def c1 (rec1. 1 2))
;=> #user.rec1{:one 1, :two 2}

(def m1 (map->rec1 {:one 1 :two 2}))
;=> #user.rec1{:one 1, :two 2}

(def r2 (->rec2 1 2))
;=> #user.rec2{:one 1, :two 2}

(def c2 (rec2. 1 2))
;=> #user.rec2{:one 1, :two 2}

(def recs [(rec1. 1 2) (->rec1 1 2)])

(for [[n m] (partition 2 (range 4))] (->rec1 n m))
;=> (#user.rec1{:one 0, :two 1} #user.rec1{:one 2, :two 3})
```